# MySQL trigger : update new table and delete old data after insert

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two similar table new data insert to `table_1` with. i want write a trigger in phpMyAdmin to update old data in `table_2` with new data that insert to `table_1` and delete `table_1` new data. ech row have unique id.

It look like simple but I do not have MySQL knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: Your question is very : If this, then this, i this, if that. Would you try constructing a solid question?

Comment: I don't see the point of table1 here maybe you can use the insert duplicate key version of insert to table 2.

Comment: post table1 and table2 structure (create table)

Answer (score 0):

You can not update the table on which the trigger is executed. MySQL locks the table when inserting to it and does not allow updating it when it is locked (which may cause a deadlock)

I think the better solution for you is to use a stored procedure. And also it seems weird to me what you are trying to achieve , you can just update table_2 with new data which is more performance wise and makes sense.

Comment: i looking for a way simple and fast to update 500 row of table with 10 columns every 10 minute it is huge DB . direct updating takes up a lot of time and server performance.

Comment: @ArthurB this way you are trying does not help in any way but can also make things worse, Stored Procedure may help you a little

Comment: @ArthurB A trigger will not speed things up compared to using two seperate queries or a procedure. So it will require about the same amount of time and server performance. (And actually, sometimes, using a trigger will be slower, as it has to execute for every row seperately). A trigger is useful e.g. to ensure data integrity (e.g. you cannot "forget" to update the second table).

Comment: any suggestion ? how to use Stored Procedure  for this case